# Prevent "head" from waiting for the stream to end

Tags: bash, svn, grep, head

```
svn log -r HEAD:1 | grep $pattern --line-buffered | awk '{print $1}'
```

The above prints out revision numbers for all commits the match the `pattern` (e.g. are done by a certain user). This works fine except it keeps streaming the entire svn log (which might be very long) and will only end after it reaches its end.

Since I only need the most recent history I've tried this:

```
svn log -r HEAD:1 | grep $pattern --line-buffered | awk '{print $1}' | head
```

However this just hangs - I'm assuming it's waiting for the stream to end but that's unacceptable to me.

How do I prevent `head` from waiting for the stream to end (and instead finish immediately after getting 10 lines)?

Comment: Does it print the 10 lines and hang ?

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything - it just waits for the input to finish.

Comment: Thats really weird...

Comment: Why don't you use `svn log --search`?

Comment: @bahrep Because I didn't know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I only need the most recent history

I think you required `-m` option with `grep`.

Try this:

```
svn log -r HEAD:1 | grep -m 1 "$pattern"
```

- `-m NUM` - Stop  reading  a  file after NUM matching lines.

Comment: Perfect! It just didn't occur to me to look for this in `grep`. I'll probably accept this answer but I'll wait some time in case other people have other working solutions.

Comment: A propos your edit: I assume they're both waiting for the stream - if `head` had a `-m` option like `grep` then that should work as well. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @NPS: `head` has an option like as you said, but it will wait until the entire stream read is complete and pick the top 10 lines, refer my answer, but @sat's answer is smart to restrict the stream read to only 10 instances

Comment: grep isn't waiting for the stream.

Comment: Might as well simplify further by getting rid of the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); `svn log -r HEAD:1 | awk -v p="$pattern" '$0 ~ p { print $1; exit }' `

Comment: @123: Can you elaborate a bit more? What I meant was `head` will operate only after `grep` command is complete getting all the instances of the search pattern and will output the `-n` lines specified. Is this the correct behavior? Or am i missing something here?

Comment: @NPS, Both commands are waiting for the stream (Input). `head` read input from `grep` and `grep` read input from `svn`. Each command's output is piping to another command(input) as soon as. Here, `head` is waiting for `grep` and `grep` is waiting for `svn`.

Comment: @tripleee Am I mistaken or does your command only print the first line/result? Also, you're correct that `grep` is unnecessary, however `awk`'s syntax doesn't make it simpler for me, quite the opposite.

Comment: @Inian Head sends sigpipe after reading 10 lines. You can see this behaviour in `yes | grep y | head`.

Comment: @123: makes sense now!

Comment: Yeah, that's to replace the `grep -m 1` in this answer. It's not hard to generalize to other numbers, but you will need a counter; ...`{ print $1; if (++c == 10) exit; }'`